# How to calculate the number of instance created between two checkpoint

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like :

```
ObjectRecorder.Start();
//Do stuff here ...
ObjectRecorder.Stop();

//And get the result
List<Object> result = ObjectRecorder.GetAll();
//or even 
ObjectRecorder.GetNumberInstanceCreated();
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am using a  `BlockingCollection` and profiling my application I saw that the TryTake is creating object internaly. As I am calling this method really often, I would like to expose the bug with a unit test and then implementing a new `ImprovedBlockingQueue` and seeing that the problem is solved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Knowing some idea of what your `//Do Stuff here` comment refers to is critical to providing a good answer.

Comment: Are you trying to store all objects created within a scope (between the `Start` and `Stop` calls?)

Comment: You're most likely going to want to look into [profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264994.aspx).

Comment: @all I want to do unit testing for avoiding garbage collection. I saw with Profiler that we are creating to much in one class. So before fixing it, I would like to reproduce it, and see that it is solved automaticaly.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve is extremely hard to achieve because you would like to inspect managed memory of the process while it is running. Such operation can be very costly and I really think a different approach to such unit test should be taken, for example you can try to to use [GC.GetTotalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to track overall memory usage. In case of isolated unit test it might be enough.

Nevertheless, I would like to mention a **possibility** to achieve what you want with help of astonishing [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx) library (which is in pre-release phase). You can attach to your running process and inspect Managed Heap like that:

```
public static void GetStats(ClrRuntime runtime)
{
    ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    var stats = heap.EnumerateObjects()
                    .Select(obj => new 
                    {
                        Type = heap.GetObjectType(obj),
                        ObjectAddress = obj
                    })
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Type,
                             g => g.Type.GetSize(g.ObjectAddress))
                    .Select(gr => new
                    {
                        Name = gr.Key.Name,
                        Count = gr.Count(),
                        Size = gr.Sum(x => (int)x)
                    })
                    .Where(t => !t.Name.StartsWith("System.") &&
                                !t.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft.") &&
                                !t.Name.Equals("Free"))
                    .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("---------- Start ----------");
    foreach (var item in stats)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {} {2}", item.Size, item.Count, item.Name);
}
```

with sample usage:

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(process.Id, 1000, AttachFlag.Passive))
{
    string dacLocation = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].TryGetDacLocation();
    ClrRuntime runtime = dataTarget.CreateRuntime(dacLocation);
    GetStats(runtime);

    List<User> list = new List<User>();
    Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList().ForEach(i => list.Add(new User() { Age = i }));

    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    GetStats(runtime);
}
```

**BUT**: For attaching to itself, only `AttachFlag.Passive` is possible which is described as:

> Performs a "passive" attach, meaning no debugger is actually attached
>   to the target process.  The process is not paused, so queries for
>   **quickly changing data (such as the contents of the GC heap or
>   callstacks)** will be highly inconsistent** unless the user pauses the
>   process through other means.

Hence it might be hard to have a deterministic stats about Managed Heap in such case.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very interesting. I will play a little with this, at least by curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps:

```
class ObjectRecorder
{
    static List<ObjectRecorder> valuse=new List<ObjectRecorder>();

    bool record = false;

    public ObjectRecorder()
    {
        //your code
        if (record){ valuse.Add(this); }
    }

    public void StartRecording(){ record = true; }

    public void StopRecording(){ record = false; }

    public void ResetRecording()
    {
        valuse = new List<ObjectRecorder>();
    }

    public List<ObjectRecorder> GetAll()
    {
        return valuse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow I doubt the OP only wants the number of `ObjectRecorder` instances created, going by the fact that `GetAll()` returns a `List<object>`

Comment: @millimoose i'm looking for you comment. let me know if I can do better.

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad - The problem is this is not giving me all the object created, only the object created in the method where I can change the constructor. Good idea else, thank you!